# Why xss module returns from 0 (number) to empty string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xss

I want to validate every input using [xss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss) module in nodejs.
But when I input 0 (number), it returns empty string.

```
var xss = require('xss');
console.log(xss(0)); //return empty string
console.log(xss('0')); //return 0
console.log(xss(5)); //return 5
```

Could anyone guide that what is the reason behind this?

Comment: Probably because legit external input is always a string.